# Associated type for ndarray arguments in rust

Tags: rust, associated-types, rust-ndarray

I want to create an interface for a (numeric) algorithm for which I want to provide an implementation with [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/) and similar libraries (let's say [pytorch bindings](https://github.com/LaurentMazare/tch-rs))

```rust
struct A<D> {
   array: D
}

trait<D> T  {
   type ArgType;
   fn foo(&mut self, other: &ArgType);
}
```

The type of the second argument `other` should depend on the selected generic type `D`. With `ndarray`, there are two types of arrays–those owning their data and views that share their data. The best way is to accept both types seems to be something like the following:

```rust
fn bar<S>(a: &ArrayBase<S, Ix2>)
where
   S: Data<Elem = f64> {}
```

For the implementation of the trait `T` for `A` using `ndarray`, that would mean that I need something like this

```rust
use ndarray::{prelude::*, Data};
impl T<Array2<f64>> for A<Array2<f64>> {
   type ArgType<S>=ArrayBase<S: Data<Elem=f64>, Ix2>; 
   fn foo(&mut self, other: &Self::ArgType){ 
      ///
   }
}
```

Then, however, how would I add the new template parameter to `foo`. More importantly, generic associated types are not allowed in stable. I assume it would be simpler if there were a trait in `ndarray` that defined all methods, however, they are implemented directly for the `ArrayBase` type. I thought about writing a thin abstraction layer but that would be too complex (even if I only use a small subset of methods only). The [`asarray`](http://rust-ndarray.github.io/ndarray/temporary/box-art-doc/ndarray/trait.AsArray.html) trait seemed to be a promising solution but it requires an lifetime parameter too (is there even a concept of associated traits?).

What would be the recommended way of handling this kind of situation; is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach is what you want:

```rust
use ndarray::{ArrayBase, Ix2};

trait TheAlgorithm<OtherArg> {
    fn calculate(&self, other: &OtherArg) -> f64;
}

impl<ReprSelf, ReprOther> TheAlgorithm<ArrayBase<ReprOther, Ix2>>
    for ArrayBase<ReprSelf, Ix2>
where
    ReprSelf: ndarray::Data<Elem = f64>,
    ReprOther: ndarray::Data<Elem = f64>,
{
    fn calculate(&self, other: &ArrayBase<ReprOther, Ix2>) -> f64 {
        // dummy calculation
        self.view()[(0, 0)] + other.view()[(0, 0)]
    }
}
```

This lets you call the `calculate()` method on either owned arrays or views, and the `other` argument can be owned or a view in either case.

Comment: Thanks, I aim at creating an implementation of a complex algorithm where individual steps can be selected–I am using structural composition. So implementing the trait for the array class is not flexible enough.

Comment: If you could edit your question to elaborate on that, I might be able to help more. Your question mostly talks about low-level details, but it lacks enough high-level context about how this API is to be used, and what usage patterns the API must support.